# How to resize a browser in flex

Tags: apache-flex, browser

I would like to open a new windows when a user clicks on a button so I would like to resize the browser (for example let's say I get the screen size (width) is 1000, I want to resize it to 700px and then launch a window next to the browser that is 300px in width and 100% in height. How do I resize the browser window using flex (and how do I get the current size of the browser).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ExternalInterface` to run JavaScript commands.